# Why this stored procedure doesn't work on MySql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insercion_anime;

delimiter $$
create procedure insercion_anime (IN nombre_anime VARCHAR(200), IN a_english_name VARCHAR(200))
begin
      insert into anime (name, english_name) values (nombre_anime, a_english_name) ;
end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: How are you executing this command? You cannot use "delimiter" everywhere (or rather: with every client).

Comment: Hi. this command  is executing on MySql